# Xcode search paths for public headers in dependencies

Tags: objective-c, xcode, dependency-management

I am trying to clean up some of my projects, and one of the things that are puzzling me is how to deal with header files in static libraries that I have added as "project dependencies" (by adding the project file itself). The basic structure is like this:

```
MyProject.xcodeproj
  Contrib
    thirdPartyLibrary.xcodeproj
  Classes
    MyClass1.h
    MyClass1.m
    ...
```

Now, the dependencies are all set up and built correctly, but how can I specify the public headers for "thirdPartyLibrary.xcodeproj" so that they are on the search path when building MyProject.xcodeproj. Right now, I have hard-coded the include directory in the thirdPartyLibrary.xcodeproj, but obviously this is clumsy and non-portable. I assume that, since the headers are public and already built to some temporary location in ~/Library (where the .a file goes as well), there is a neat way to reference this directory. Only.. how? An hour of Googling turned up blank, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is a project-relative path too "clumsy and non-portable"?  That's generally what I do, but it's also possible to point at the shared build directory if you'd prefer.

Comment: This is also what I do, but I was hoping for a better way of doing it, that doesn't require me to manipulate the paths at all. Xcode puts the public headers in the "Derived sources" location, but I can't find a way to include this location automagically.

Comment: As bounty is going to expire in 24 hours, I'm going to award already marked answer ;-) Damian, enjoy your 100 new points ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your solution is sufficient and a generally accepted one.  One alternative would be to have all header files located under an umbrella directory that can describe the interface to using the depended-on libraries and put that in your include path.  I see this as being similar to /usr/include.  Another alternative that I have never personally tried, but I think would work would be to create references to all the headers of *thirdPartyLibrary* from *MyProject* so that they appear to be members of the *MyProject*.  You would do this by dragging them from some location into *MyProject*, and then deselecting the checkbox that says to copy them into the project's top level directory. From one perspective this seems feasible to me because it is as if you are explicitly declaring that your project depends on those specific classes, but it is not directly responsible for compiling them.

One of the things to be wary of when addressing this issue is depending on implementation-specific details of Xcode for locating libraries automatically.  Doing so may seem innocuous in the meantime but the workflows that it uses to build projects are subject to change with updates and could potentially break your project in subtle and confusing ways.  If they are not well-defined in some documentation, I would take any effect as being coincidental and not worth leveraging in your project when you can enforce the desired behavior by some other means.  In the end, you may have to define a convention that you follow or find one that you adopt from someone else. By doing so, you can rest assured that if your solution is documented and reproducible, any developer (including yourself in the future) can pick it up and proceed without tripping over it, and that it will stand the testament of time.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer. I still think it is confusing that public headers exported from dependencies are not put on the include path, and that it is not possible to create (static) framework projects for iOS. But what can one do? I am still hoping there is a better way...

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, I believe you want to add a path containing $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR) to the HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS in your projects build settings.

As an example, I took an existing iOS project which contains a static library, which is included just in the way you describe, and set the libraries header files to public. I also noted that the PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH for this project was set to "/usr/local/include" and these files are copied to $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/usr/local/include when the parent project builds the dependent project. So, the solution was to add $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/usr/local/include to HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS in my project's build settings.

```
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/usr/local/include
```

Your situation may be slightly different but the exact path your looking for can probably be found in [Xcode's build settings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/0-Introduction/introduction.html). Also you may find it helpful to add a Run Script build phase to your target and note the values of various settings at build time with something like:

```
echo "BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR " $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR
echo "HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS " $HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS
echo "PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH " $PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH
.
.
.
etc.
```

Comment: But $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR) differs in parent/child projects. When I set $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR) in parent project, it doesn't work, because child project is built in different directory (different $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)).

Comment: BTW I already did find a solution for this - read https://devforums.apple.com/message/414778 Solution is Xcode4 Workspace, because all products/libraries/... are build in the same directory. Advantage of this solution is also the fact that your application will use only public header files (marked in build phases).

Comment: $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/usr/local/include solved this problem for me with a parent/child projects relationship. The dependent project got built into the main project's $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR). This was with Xcode 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

The way we do it is to go into build target settings for the main project and add:

```
User Header Search Path = "Contrib"
```

and check that it searches recursively. We don't see performance problems with searching recursively even with many (10-15 in some projects) dependencies.

Comment: Maybe not performance problems, but you could end up in name conflicts, since this will also include the private headers.